# Extract portion of branch name for prepare commit message in Git

Tags: regex, git, sed, hook

I want to prepend every commit message with a *portion* of my branch name.  For example lets say my branch naming convention is the following:

`issueType/repoName-issueNumber --> bug/myRepo-123`

I want my commit message to go from

```
added missing semicolon
```

to

```
myRepo-123 : added missing semicolon
```

So far in my prepare-commit-msg file I have the following but it is printing out the entire branch name

```
#!/bin/sh
NAME=$(git branch | grep '*' | sed 's/* //')
STORY_NUMBER=$(echo $NAME | sed 's/.*\(myRepo-[0-9]\+\.log\).*/\1/')
echo "$STORY_NUMBER" : $(cat "$1") > "$1"
```

... renders ...

```
bug/myRepo-123 : added missing semicolon
```

What edits do I need to make to the regex to extract everything AFTER `/`?

Thanks

Comment: What does `git branch` output? Need to know it to construct the message

Comment: Are you just looking for the name of the branch? It's `bug/myRepo-123`

Comment: So, `git branch` outputs `bug/myRepo-123`? Fair enough! Do you need a script? (or) are you planning to run a set of commands

Comment: I have a script above that lives inside prepare-commit-msg in my ./git folder.  My issue is my regex is not correct `'s/.*\(myRepo-[0-9]\+\.log\).*/\1/'`.  It renders the entire branch name while I only want it to render `myRepo-123`.

Comment: To debug your regex, we need to know what output you are applying it on? I need the complete output of `git branch`

Comment: I only have one branch so the output is simply my branch name.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132218/discussion-between-inian-and-user1876246).

Comment: Can you check my answer to see if thats what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding a really great question and answer that helped me solve my problem.  It can be found here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24140/return-only-the-portion-of-a-line-after-a-matching-pattern

In the end this was my script which prints out `myRepo-123: commit message`

```
#!/bin/sh
BRANCH_NAME=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD)
STORY_NUMBER=$(echo $BRANCH_NAME | sed -n -e 's/^.*\(myRepo-\)/\1/p')
echo "$STORY_NUMBER": $(cat "$1") > "$1"
```

Before I explain how I modified the regex it's worth noting that I found an easier way to get my current branch name using the `--short` flag on the symbolic ref command.

The following is taken from the other stack exchange answer for the regex

Detailed explanation:

- -n means not to print anything by default.
- -e is followed by a sed command. s is the pattern replacement command.
- The regular expression ^.*stalled: matches the pattern
  you're looking for, plus any preceding text (.* meaning any text,
  with an initial ^ to say that the match begins at the beginning of
  the line). Note that if stalled: occurs several times on the line,
  this will match the last occurrence.
- The match, i.e. everything on the line up to stalled:, is replaced by
  the empty string (i.e. deleted).
- The final p means to print the transformed line.
- If you want to retain the matching portion, use a
  backreference: \1 in the replacement part designates what is
  inside a group (…) in the pattern. Here, you could write
  stalled: again in the replacement part; this feature is useful
  when the pattern you're looking for is more general than a simple 
  string.